# Parent category not display first in array?

Tags: codeigniter

My model function get forums is not showing the correct order or my parent and sub categories.

The parent category **PHP** should be first at top of array because it is THE parent of category 46, 45

> **Question**: How can I get it to make sure it displays correct order

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fid] => 46
            [pid] => 41
            [name] => password_hash
        )

    [1] => Array // Parent Category
        (
            [fid] => 41
            [pid] => 0
            [name] => PHP
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fid] => 45
            [pid] => 41
            [name] => str_replace
        )

)
```

Model

```
public function get_forums($pid = '0') {
    $categories_data = array();

    $this->db->where('pid', $pid);
    $this->db->or_where('pid >', $pid);
    $this->db->order_by('name', 'asc');

    $query = $this->db->get('forum');

    foreach ($query->result() as $result) {

    $categories_data[] = array(
    'fid' => $result->fid,
    'pid' => $result->pid,            
    'name' => $result->name
    );

    if ($result->pid > 0) {

    $category_children[] = $this->make_parent_list($result->pid);

    if ($category_children) {
    $categories = array_merge($category_children, $categories_data);
    }      

    }

    }

    return $categories_data;

}

function make_parent_list($fid) {
        $forum_data = array();


        $forum_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM forum WHERE fid = '" . (int)$fid . "'");

        foreach ($forum_query->result() as $forum) {

            if ($forum->pid > 0) {

                $forum_data[] = array(
                    'pid' => $forum->pid,
                );

                $forum_children = $this->make_parent_list($forum->pid);

                if ($forum_children) {
                    $forum_data = array_merge($forum_children, $forum_data);
                }           

            }
        }

        return $forum_data;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the ordering. Change this

```
$this->db->order_by('name', 'asc');
```

with something like this:

```
$this->db->order_by('fid', 'asc');
```

You can then order the results by the name too, adding it as secondary:

```
 $this->db->order_by('fid', 'asc');
 $this->db->order_by('name', 'asc');
```

Comment: Is it possible to sort the parent category names as well I tried it with name does not sort parent names

Comment: No luck with sorting the parent category names. with the order by but the other one worked for fid.

Comment: mysqli and https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html I have updated question with the function which I call it in the get_forums

Comment: This should work though. Try **$this->db->order_by('fid asc, name asc');** If not, you should check the query with **echo $this->db->last_query();** after **$query = $this->db->get('forum');**